# What is the meaning of すると in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

> おじいさん は びっくりして その たけ を そっと きって みました。
>
> **すると** どう でしょう。 <-- this one
>
> たけ の なか に 小さな 女の子 が いました。

I know that Suruto is "hereupon/thereupon/at this point". But "at this point, how is it?" doesn't make a good translation...

Can you help ? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The すると here is a 接続詞(conjunction), meaning "and", "then", "and just then", etc.
See [this J-J dictionary definition #1](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/120556/meaning/m0u/) or [this J-E dictionary](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8).

どうでしょう literally means "How is ~~?", but here it's an exclamation rather than interrogative, and means "to my surprise," "Good God!", "behold!" etc. It's similar to (but probably sounds more literary than) 「なんということでしょう！」, 「なんてことだ(ろう)！」 etc.

[This dictionary](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86) carries the sentence 「するとどうでしょう！」 as a translation for "And behold!"